# Conditional probability when selecting two bulbs

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A box contains four 40W light bulbs, five 60W bulbs and six 75W bulbs.

If two bulbs are randomly selected from the box of light bulbs, and at least one of them is found to be rated 75W, what is the probability that both of them are 75-W bulbs?
$$
P(X=2\mid X\geq1)=\frac{P(X=2)}{P(X\geq1)}=\frac{P(X=2)}{1-P(X=0)}
$$

I did not follow this solution
Isn't P(A|B) = P(A and B)/P(B)

Why is there no "and" component in the given solution?

My foundation for probability is extremely weak so I apologize if this question is a bit too basic or something. And due to low reputation (extremely new here) I couldn't just ask this in a comment on the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to follow the analysis in your question.  Therefore, I answered your question from scratch.

---

$A$ is event that both are 75w. 
$B$ is event that at least one is 75w.

By [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)
$\displaystyle P(A|B) = \frac{p(AB)}{p(B)}$.

$p(B)$ can be computed by considering that there may be either one or two 75w bulbs.

$\displaystyle p(B) = \frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{9}{1}}{\binom{15}{2}}
+ \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{15}{2}}.$

$\displaystyle p(AB) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{15}{2}}.$

Comment: By P(AB) do you mean P(A and B)?

Comment: @ShivamUpadhyay yes, exactly.

Comment: My question was around calculating P(A and B). I am not sure how you reached the value you wrote above. What is the formula for this? Or am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: @ShivamUpadhyay Here, if you look at the specification for events $A$ and $B$, you realize that if event $A$ occurs, then event $B$ automatically occurs.  So, for this particular problem, $p(AB) = p(A)$.  In general, for Bayes Theorem problems, this type of shortcut will not be true.  It just happens to be true in this case.

Comment: It is reasonable to assume if such a case is not applicable, the problem would clearly specify what P(A and B) is? Otherwise it's not really solvable?

Comment: @ShivamUpadhyay I am sorry, I don't understand your last comment.  Are you able to understand my analysis?  If not, do you have questions about my analysis?  Also, re your last comment, could you please re-word your question?

Comment: I could follow your analysis. Disregard my last comment. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

The numerator  **is** $P(A\, and\, B)$

If you draw a Venn Diagram, you will realize that the set $A$ is totally included in set $B$ so the numerator will simply be $P(A)$

Comment: That is what I was thinking the reason was. But if it wasn't entirely a subset, is there any way we could have calculated P(A and B)?

Comment: @ShivamUpadhyay if $A$ is a subset of $B$ then $A\cap B = A$

Comment: @Shivam Upadhyay: Of course. It would depend on what the given data was. You can have a look at fundamental concepts at https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Probability/ConditionalProbability.shtml. Basically you will need to compute $P(A \,and\, B)$ , nowadays written as $P(A\cap B)$ whenever there is a portion where the two sets have a *portion* that intersects.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja In general, for problems of this type, calculating $p(A \cap B)$ is straightforward.  When you have two events, $A$ and $B$, you have to ask what the chances are that both events are true.  For example, suppose that $A$ is the event that when a die is thrown, the number is $\leq 3$.  Suppose that $B$ is the event that when a die is thrown, the number is even.  Then, $p(A \cap B) = (1/6)$, since the only way that events $A$ and $B$ can both occur is if a $(2)$ is thrown.